# First image in fancy box slide show appears twice

Tags: jquery

I am using the fancy box script to show six pictures in a slide show. I have been using the same script at several pages, but at this one, the first image appears twice, and I can't find the reason why. This is my code:

```
    <div id="actividadesofertas"> <a  class="fancybox"  rel="gallery01" href="eventos/Aquagym.jpg" title= "AQUAGYM 1/6" id="launcher"><img src="images_club/actividadesofertas.png">
    <div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "BONOS ALQUILER 2/6" href="eventos/Bonos_alquiler.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "CICLO 3/6" href="eventos/Ciclo.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "PEQUE TENIS/PADEL 4/6" href="eventos/PEQUES-padel_tenis.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "PILATES 5/6" href="eventos/Pilates.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "ZUMBA 6/6" href="eventos/Zumba.jpg"></a>


        </div>

    </div>
```

The first image appears as first and as second image in the slide show.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot to close the a tag for the first image**

```
<div id="actividadesofertas"> 
    <a  class="fancybox"  rel="gallery01" href="eventos/Aquagym.jpg" title= "AQUAGYM 1/6" id="launcher">
        <img src="images_club/actividadesofertas.png">
    </a> <!-- INCLUDE THIS -->
    <div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "BONOS ALQUILER 2/6" href="eventos/Bonos_alquiler.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "CICLO 3/6" href="eventos/Ciclo.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "PEQUE TENIS/PADEL 4/6" href="eventos/PEQUES-padel_tenis.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "PILATES 5/6" href="eventos/Pilates.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "ZUMBA 6/6" href="eventos/Zumba.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```